# Gaomon S620 configuration?

Tags: release-hera, settings, tablet

eOS Hera, I have the following problem:
The graphics tablet (256c:006d) works in principle, but since I use two monitors, drawings are heavily distorted.

I can not configure the tablet because the output of xsetwacom is empty.

I've installed libwacom, therefore.

libwacom-list-local-devices

```
# Device node: /dev/input/event258
[Device]
Name=GAOMON S620
ModelName=
DeviceMatch=usb:256c:006d:GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pen;usb:256c:006d:GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad;
Class=Bamboo
Width=6
Height=4
IntegratedIn=
Layout=gaomon-s620.svg
Styli=0xffffd;

[Features]
Reversible=true
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=false
TouchSwitch=false
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=4

[Buttons]
Left=A;B;C;D;
# Right=
# Top=
# Bottom=
# Touchstrip=
# Touchstrip2=
# OLEDs=
# Ring=
# Ring2=
EvdevCodes=0x100;0x101;0x102;0x103;
RingNumModes=0
Ring2NumModes=0
StripsNumModes=0

---------------------------------------------------------------
# Device node: /dev/input/event257
[Device]
Name=GAOMON S620
ModelName=
DeviceMatch=usb:256c:006d:GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pen;usb:256c:006d:GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pad;
Class=Bamboo
Width=6
Height=4
IntegratedIn=
Layout=gaomon-s620.svg
Styli=0xffffd;

[Features]
Reversible=true
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=false
TouchSwitch=false
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=4

[Buttons]
Left=A;B;C;D;
# Right=
# Top=
# Bottom=
# Touchstrip=
# Touchstrip2=
# OLEDs=
# Ring=
# Ring2=
EvdevCodes=0x100;0x101;0x102;0x103;
RingNumModes=0
Ring2NumModes=0
StripsNumModes=0
```

It's also listed as a pointing device:

xinput --list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ Paten USB Gaming Mouse id=11 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ Contour Design ShuttleXpress id=12 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ HID 0566:3013 Consumer Control id=15 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pen Pen (0) id=22 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ GAOMON Gaomon Tablet Pen id=10 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Contour Design ShuttleXpress id=20 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ HID 0566:3013 System Control id=16 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ HID 0566:3013 id=13 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ HID 0566:3013 Consumer Control id=21 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ HID 0566:3013 id=14 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

I have installed https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-wacom
But I still cannot configure the tablet. :-(

What is my thinking error?

TIA
Cheers
Mierscheid

Comment: I've bought the same tablet and I'm still working on make it works. Could you tell me how do you make it works? I've been trying with digimend and also opentabletdriver but not lucky yet.

Comment: Can you provide specific details on the device, what you've tried, and what isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: Device: Gaomon S620 (256c:006d). First I've tried just to connect, but it doesn't work. After that I tried to install digimend drivers, first by source , it doesn't works (xsetwacom --list devices returns nothing) then installing digimend by deb package (version 9) and it found my tablet but not properly working and not able to configure it. I remove digimend and tried with opentabletdriver (gaomon s620 full supported is said in its project page) but doesn't works (I'm still trying the steps on faq page from opentabletdriver in orderto solve it, but not lucky yet)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my post on [GitHub](https://github.com/bigbigmdm/GAOMON-S620-in-LINUX). This is for Debian, but I think this method is good for ElementaryOS as well.

Comment: This answer may offer a solution, but posting to an external website is generally frowned upon. Can you [edit] the answer to include the key parts that solve the problem? The link can remain as a source, but the answer should able to stand on its own merit 